# Batch start command not opening program

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

When I enter the following from a command prompt:

```
start myprog.exe
```

It opens the program in a command window, but it doesn't start the actual program itself.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
start /b "" "myprog.exe"
```

See `start /?` for more help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `START` just have `myprog.exe`, make sure that the program can be found. Put the directory for it in the `PATH` environment variable if necessary.

If you want to continue processing more commands in the batch file use the `/B` switch for `START`, see syntax here [Microsoft DOS start command](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm#03).